# Error spotting : One who perpetually hesitates which of the two things he will do first will ultimately do neither

Tags: tense, exam-questions

> **Error spotting** : One who perpetually hesitates which of the two things
>   he will do first will ultimately do neither
>
> One who perpetually hesitates (A) which of the two things he will do first (B) will ultimately do neither. (C) no error .

Is this sentence grammatically correct ? 
Isn't the B part wrong? We don't use two *will* in single sentence , right ? So shouldn't the correct form be :

> One who perpetually hesitates which of the two things he will do first will ultimately do neither.

Comment: No, you're wrong. This is how I read the sentence: *[ One who perpetually hesitates which of the two things he will do first ] will ultimately do neither.*, i.e., *One [...] will ultimately do neither [of the two things].* I'd hesitate to put a comma after *first*, but it might aid the reader.

Comment: Both _"will"_ s are required because both _do_ verbs are in the future tense. I would personally add in "when deciding", and I might remove the "the", but I'm not sure there are any grammatical errors in the sentence. _One who perpetually hesitates **when deciding** which of two things he will do first will ultimately do neither._

Comment: @SteveES I believe B is grammatically incorrect because it is not native speech to *hesitate between two things*.  *Hesitate* is sort of like *zero* in that *hesitate* is a null action and no matter how many possible decisions there are it always comes back simply null.  One *hesitates* (period).  2x0 = 0 but in describing the answer to this equation you don't say *zero which of two things* you just say *zero*.  I had many options but I *hesitated* (not *I hesitated which of many options*).

Comment: Or if you did nothing you don't say you *did nothing which of five things* you just *did nothing* (period).

Answer (score 1):

> "One who perpetually hesitates (A) which of the two things he will do first (B) will ultimately do neither. (C) no error."

Whatever this is, it is not a sentence. With the A,B,C points it feels like it is a multiple-choice question, except that, of the three endings, only one (B) fits with the beginning.

> One who perpetually hesitates will ultimately do neither.

I also wonder if the point of this exercise is to insert something at one of the points A, B or C to make a sentence? You could make a sentence by saying:

> One who perpetually hesitates **over** which of the two things he will do first will ultimately do neither.

If this doesn't answer your question then perhaps you can add some context so it can be understood better.

Comment: Note: I have edited the question to copy the OP's target sentence from the title to the question. I think that should clear things up.

Answer (score -2):

> **Error spotting** : One who perpetually hesitates which of the two things
>   he will do first will ultimately do neither
>
> One who perpetually hesitates (A) which of the two things he will do first (B) will ultimately do neither. (C) no error .

The question is not very clear. My correction would be, "One who perpetually hesitates **as to** which of the two things he will do first will ultimately do neither.

However I have a sneaking suspicion that your teacher might (wrongly) want you to answer "No error".